# Thread 3: EXC_BAD_ACCESS (code=2, address=0x700004f09ff8) Generics and Recursion

Tags: swift, generics, recursion, stack

Not sure why bad access is happening in this situation.  The stack has an apparent depth of 1525 calls.  I think that is too shallow for a stack overflow, but I'm not sure.  When I try to print the object I get: `po firstCodable error: Trying to put the stack in unreadable memory at: 0x700004f09f80.`

```
extension Array {
    
    func isOutOfBounds(index: Int) -> Bool {
        count <= index || index < 0
    }
}

typealias PromiseAction = (Data?, URLResponse?, Error?) -> Void

protocol Promisable {
    
    func session(_ promiseAction: @escaping PromiseAction) -> URLSessionDataTask
}

extension Array where Element: Promisable {
    
    func getCodableRecurse<T: Codable>(
        index: Int = 0,
        expressive: Bool = true,
        completion: @escaping ([T]) -> Void
    ) {
        if expressive {
            print("urls progress: \(Double(index) / Double(count))")
        }
        if isEmpty {
            completion([])
            return
        }
        if isOutOfBounds(index: index) {
            completion([])
        }
        self[index].getCodable { (codable: T?) in
            let clap = codable
            getCodableRecurse(index: index + 1) { (codables: [T]) in
                var codables: [T] = codables
                clap.flatMap {
                    codables.append($0)
                }
                completion(codables)
            }
        }
    }
    
}

typealias DataAction = (Data) -> Void

extension Decodable {
    init?(_ data: Data) {
        do {
            self = try JSONDecoder().decode(Self.self, from: data)
        } catch let err {
            print(err)
            return nil
        }
    }
}

extension Promisable {
    
    func getCodable<T: Codable>(expressive: Bool = true, _ action: @escaping (T?)->Void) {
        getData { (data) in
            guard expressive else {
                action(T(data))
                return
            }
            if let codable = T(data) {
                /// Expected to decode Double but found a number instead.means the value should be Bool
                action(codable)
            } else {
                /// Gateway Timeout means the server did not respond quickly enough.
                action(nil)
            }
        }
    }
    
    func getData(_ dataAction: DataAction? = nil) {
        sessionDataTask(provideData: dataAction).resume()
    }
    
    func sessionDataTask(provideData: DataAction?) -> URLSessionDataTask {
        session { data, response, error in
            guard let data = data else {
                print("ERROR: data was nil for the call from: \(self), ")
                return
            }
            provideData?(data)
        }
    }
}

extension URLRequest: Promisable {
    
    func session(_ promiseAction: @escaping PromiseAction) -> URLSessionDataTask {
        URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: self, completionHandler: promiseAction)
    }
}

extension URL: Promisable {
    
    func session(_ promiseAction: @escaping PromiseAction) -> URLSessionDataTask {
        URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: self, completionHandler: promiseAction)
    }
}
```

Comment: Why are you using recursion, at all? Isn't this just a `flatMap` operation?

Comment: Not sure what you mean.  I usually associate flatMap for flattening matrices, but I'm not using any.  Are you talking about flatMap for optionals?  I think that would unwrap the optional just the same as binding but when I swap that out, I still get the same runtime error.

Comment: Ah I thought there was a nested loop in the `self[index].getCodable { (codable: T?) in` closure. So isn't this just a regular `map`, with completion handlers being called? I don't get the point of the `firstCodable` (why is it called that? there is no `secondCodable`)

Comment: These are web calls, so they are using escaping closures unlike with map.

Comment: (I'm playing compiler in my head, because this example isn't compilable and runnable, off-the-cuff thinking is all I can really do to help you.) It looks to me like the entire array extension has semantics roughly equivalent to `completion(self.map { $0.getCodable.map { [$0] } ?? [] })`

Comment: Is `getCodable` what's doing the web calls?

Comment: I'm sorry I thought I included everything.  It compiles and runs on my end.  And if you add conformance to Promisable for the URL, then it should compile and run on your end as well.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/225794/discussion-between-alexander-and-scottyblades).

Comment: Also, `self` is not an array of codable, `self` is an array of `URL` or array of URLRequest.

Comment: I updated the question @Alexander